# Wi-Fi stops working after some time

Tags: linux, linux-mint, wifi

Lenovo Z50-70. After some time (couldn't find any pattern here) Wi-Fi just stops working. It shows that connection is fine, but I can't open any page in browser (connection refused). I tried switching it on/off, restarting router and reinstalling wi-fi driver.

I only have this problem on linux (currently on linux mint). It is fine and works perfectly on windows for DAYS.

I don't know if it helps, here is lspci output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller 
(rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
```

Comment: I recently experienced this problem on Lenovo X201 and it turned out the the problem was with my ISP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall `RTL8723BE` driver.

Install `build-essential` and `linux-headers` :

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
```

Download the newest driver from [here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new).

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new
```

Compile:

```
cd rtlwifi_new
make clean
sudo make install
```

Unload and load the driver:

```
modprobe -r rtl8723be
modprobe rtl8723be
```

To keep your network alive you need to create a new configuration file `rtl8723be.conf`

```
nano /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

with the following line:

```
options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N
```

Save and reboot your machine.