# (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) Internet stops working after some time

Tags: ubuntu, networking, network-interface

I'm using an IdeaPad Gaming 3 15ARH05.

WiFI just stops working after using it for a bit. Sometimes this happens after minutes, other times it takes hours. My other devices can connect to the modem and use the internet just fine, so this is an issue specific to my laptop.

Some things I've tried to fix this was turning off power management in iwconfig and reinstalling the network manager. Reinstalling the network manager actually fixed the issue for a few days but the problem came back.

This seems to be similar to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283122/wi-fi-stops-working-after-some-time)
but unfortunately the link in that question is dead and I don't quite understand the solution so I figured I'll make a new question.

The wifi on the top right appears connected. Trying to ping gives me these results:

[image]

Let me know if there's any additional info I can add.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it on proxy, try removing the socks proxy by removing the proxy address and set port = 0.